# How to create a auto blog system for website

Tags: html, css, weblogic, blogs

I want to crate a blog website where people can create their blog on post it on my website. But i dont want to do it manually takimg each post and uploading by my self

How can i create a coding for it tht people create the blog and it gets uploaded by itself on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to learn few programming languages , you need a back-end and front-end knowledge,

--- brief explanation

***Front-End:*** is what the user will see to be able to create a post, for example the title tags, the forms, etc..

***Back-end:*** is what absorbs the information that the user inputs in the forms and stores it in to a database, is like the logic part.

If you don't have any idea of what this is, you should try[Wordpreess](https://wordpress.org/)
And then start modifying some of the code to practice. Wordpress will allow you to create your own blog and even give permissions to other users to create the post or make a platform.

Good Luck.

Comment: Does wordpress allow other users to make their post and upload it to my website such that the posts get automatically on the site without me manually adding it

Comment: @Shantanuvidwans it does! Research there are a lot of videos in youtube that can help you, Wordpress is one of the most used platforms.

Comment: Thanks to help me out

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make a form so that user can write post. and then using back-end programming upload it in your website. you may use php to do so....

Comment: What is back-end programing and aboit that php, i will have to learn it to make my blogging website

Comment: back end programming is a programming where you handle the user events,connection to database  and many others thinks..you can learn php (one of the programming language) if you want...